# How is a token replaced in a file for a Gradle build product?

Tags: java, replace, gradle, token

I have a normal buildscript for Gradle set up, and one thing I want to do is have the version of my build specified. This is the code I've set up to replace the version token in my main Java source file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

processResources {
    from (sourceSets.main.java) {
        include 'T145/myproj/Main.java'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['@VERSION@' : project.version])
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work. I tried using the `replace` function, but that didn't prove to be a success either. My `Main.java` has a public variable `VERSION` that equals `@VERSION@`, and that is what I want to be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I'm seeing in the [Gradle manual example of ReplaceTokens](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#filterOnCopy), you want to get rid of the @'s in your filter line, so that it reads:

```
filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION : project.version])
```

Gradle assumes that the token it's looking for has the @'s delimiting it already, so it is trying to replace @@VERSION@@ instead of @VERSION@, like you want.

Comment: Well, I changed that but it still doesn't work for some reason. I even changed the task from `processResources` to `jar`, since that is the task that specifically handles outputting the release.

Comment: Did you try putting the filter line outside of the from closure?  Every example of filter I've seen with filter does not put it into a closure with from.

Comment: for me it replaces token but project.version is unspecified