# How does Gradle's CopySpec filter method signature relate to the example given?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, named-parameters, positional-parameter

I am trying to implement something that will replace `${pattern}` in xml files in my build.gradle file:

```
processResources {
    eachFile { FileCopyDetails fileCopyDetails ->
        if (fileCopyDetails.name.contains("blueprint.xml")) {
            project.logger.quiet "Processing: " + fileCopyDetails.path
            logger.quiet "" + project.ext.properties.entrySet()
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [prop1, value, prop2, value])
        }
    }
}
```

`tokens:` appears to take a Map. Again, how does this relate to the function signature?

Convert all properties with String values into a Map for input into `tokens:`

```
def tokenMap = new LinkedHashMap()
def stringProps = project.ext.properties.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof String }
stringProps.each { entry -> tokenMap.put(entry.key, entry.value)}
```

A look at the Gradle Javadoc reveals a filter function whose signature does not seem to match the examples. **Particularly, the `Map<String,?>` and `Class<? extends FilterReader>` do not match the order in the examples as far as I understand them.** Could somebody map the example to the function signature so that I understand what is going on?

> ```
> CopySpec filter​(Map<String,​?> properties,
>             Class<? extends FilterReader> filterType)
> ```
>
> Adds a content filter to be used during the copy. Multiple calls to
>   filter, add additional filters to the filter chain. Each filter should
>   implement java.io.FilterReader. Include org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
>   for access to all the standard Ant filters.
>
> Filter properties may be specified using groovy map syntax.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> filter(HeadFilter, lines:25, skip:2)
> filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:[copyright:'2009', version:'2.3.1'])
> ```
>
> **Specified by**:
>
> `filter` in interface `ContentFilterable`
>
> **Parameters**:
>   `properties` - map of filter properties
>   `filterType` - Class of filter to add
>
> **Returns**:
>       this

---

Related:

[How is a token replaced in a file for a Gradle build product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627918/how-is-a-token-replaced-in-a-file-for-a-gradle-build-product?rq=1)

---

Note:

What does not work is the SimpleTemplateEngine

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/features.xml") {
        // expand uses Groovy's SimpleTemplateEngine
        project.logger.quiet "Processing: " + file
        expand project.getProperties()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the underlying Groovy syntax. Groovy allows you to specify method parameters by name (i.e. `<name>: <value>`) whenever the first parameter to the method is declared as a `Map`. Crucially, named parameters can appear *at any point* in the argumemt list, even after so-called positional parameters (i.e. those declared after the `Map` in the method signature), and they will be put as entries in the initial `Map` parameter. See the section **Mixing named and positional parameters** in the [Groovy Language Documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_parameters_2) for more details.

So, the Gradle `filter` method has signature

```
CopySpec filter​(Map<String,​?> properties, Class<? extends FilterReader> filterType)
```

The first `properties` parameter is of type `Map`, so this method can be called with named parameters. In addition, there is one more *positional parameter*, `filterType`. So, to call this method, you must specify one parameter without a name, of type `Class<? extends FilterReader>`, which will be used for `filterType`, and zero or more named parameters, which will all be put in the `properties` Map.

Taking one of the examples from the documentation:

```
filter(HeadFilter, lines:25, skip:2)
```

will mean that `filter` is called with

```
properties = [
  lines: 25,
  skip: 2
]
filterType = HeadFilter
```

Any of the following calls would be equivalent:

```
filter(lines:25, skip:2, HeadFilter)
filter(lines:25, HeadFilter, skip:2)
filter([lines:25, skip:2], HeadFilter)
```

The last call here passes both parameters positionally (you don't *have* to use named parameters when the first parameter is declared as a `Map`).

#### Aside Note

I'm intrigued as to why using `expand` doesn't work - it should!

Comment: Ok, the problem with expand() has nothing to do with XML. It has to do with the error handling of expand()/SimpleTemplateEngine, which fails if a property is not found within an XML. It is silly behavior. I am not sure how to properly swallow the exception. There is even a ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5093

Comment: This is because I am processing all properties regardless of whether they exist in the template.